# Roundcube install, getting MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS fatal error

Tags: php, pdo, fatal-error, roundcube

I'm installing Roundcube 0.9.0 on a shared host server.

I have PHP 5.3.8 with PDO activated however when i'm installing roundcube, this is what response I get:

```
Check DB config
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS' in /home/neuas/domains/anthonysalvador.info/public_html/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_db_mysql.php on line 127
```

I have contacted my host, they turned me away. I contacted Roundcube, they turned me away. Is there something I could be overlooking?

here is the PDO section of the code including the faulty line:

```
102    protected function dsn_options($dsn)
103    {
104    $result = array();
105
106    if (!empty($dsn['key'])) {
107        $result[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_KEY] = $dsn['key'];
108    }
109
110    if (!empty($dsn['cipher'])) {
111        $result[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_CIPHER] = $dsn['cipher'];
112    }
113
114    if (!empty($dsn['cert'])) {
115        $result[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT] = $dsn['cert'];
116    }
117
118    if (!empty($dsn['capath'])) {
119        $result[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CAPATH] = $dsn['capath'];
120    }
121
122    if (!empty($dsn['ca'])) {
123        $result[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA] = $dsn['ca'];
124    }
125
126    // Always return matching (not affected only) rows count
127    $result[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS] = true;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to a database? Seems like you have no connection.

Comment: well, i've added all my database information into it as it's been set up... is there a way to detect that connection?

Comment: I think `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` is available only **after** you execute a query.

Comment: Copy and paste the database information in another file and try to create a table with a simpele script, just to verify it works.

Comment: I ran into this issue before. It's simply a wrong PHP Level.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older topic, but I found it while searching for a solution to the same issue. Here is what worked for me. I opened db.inc.php with a text editor and looked at lines 25-28, then uncommented and edited the line that applied to my installation. That removed the error message and the install completed.

```
//$rcmail_config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://roundcube:pass@localhost/roundcubemail';
// postgres example: 'pgsql://roundcube:pass@localhost/roundcubemail';
// Warning: for SQLite use absolute path in DSN:
// sqlite example: 'sqlite:////full/path/to/sqlite.db?mode=0646';
```

Answer (score 2):

Just spent a few hours chasing this down. I am using PHP 5.3.3 with MySQL 15.1 (10.0.31 MariaDB) on Centos 6.5

For me, the fix was to obtain the mySQL-pdo so file. Fixed by performing **yum install php-mysql-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64**. That package was chosen by performing **yum whatprovides *php*pdo*.so**

I was led down this path by: 
[PHP 7 RC3: How to install missing MySQL PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728860/php-7-rc3-how-to-install-missing-mysql-pdo)

This may be overkill - and please let me know if it is, but I also specified the extension in /etc/php.ini (line 925)
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so

Answer (score 1):

Install `mysql` for php to solve this issue.
For php7.4 in debian you can use:

`apt install php7.4-mysql`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while installing some php scripts.
The solution was to install php56-pdo_mysql.
On BSD this can be done using the following command: 
pkg install php56-pdo_mysql

Hope this helps