# PHP 7 RC3: How to install missing MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, pdo, php-7

I am trying to setup webserver with `PHP 7 RC3` + `Nginx` on `Ubuntu 14.04` (for test purposes).

I installed Ubuntu in Vagrant using `ubuntu/trusty64` and PHP 7 RC 3 from Ondřej Surý (https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php-7.0).

I can not find the way to install `MySQL PDO` (PHP sees `PDO` class but not anything related to MySQL, like `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY` etc.)

Looks like there is no lib `php7.0-mysql` (by analogy with standard `php5-mysqlnd` and `php7.0-fpm` etc. from Ondřej)

Section `PDO` in `phpinfo()`:

```
PDO support      enabled
PDO drivers      no value
```

How can I get it?

Comment: You say Ubuntu 12.04, but then that you're using `ubuntu/trusty64` which is 14.04.  Assuming that you are in fact using Trusty (after all, Ondřej hasn't produced packages for Precise) then his [`php-modules`](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php-7.0/+sourcepub/5374980/+listing-archive-extra) package will provide `php-mysql`.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! (version is fixed). And your suggestion with module name works. Thanks! If you add it as answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: My mistake - i was searching like this `apt-cache search php pdo` and module `php-mysql` in this case is not shown.

Comment: If it's anything like standard Ubuntu/Debian you can also install `php5-mysqlnd` to use the [mysql native driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php#mysqli.overview.mysqlnd), which according to that link is "strongly encouraged", even if the Ubuntu devs don't use it by default.

Comment: Mike, `php5-mysqlnd` does not work for me cause I install `PHP 7`.

Comment: For PHP 7 on CentOS 7, mysqlnd package name is php70w-mysqlnd (big advantage over regular mysql driver is support of returning the correct data types [e.g. int as int, not as string]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [eggyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623041/eggyal) didn't provided his comment as answer after he gave right advice in a comment - i am posting it here: In my case I had to install module `php-mysql`. See comments under the question for details.

Answer (score 144):

For thoses running Linux with apache2 you need to install php-mysql

```
apt-get install php-mysql
```

or if you are running ubuntu 16.04 or higher just running the following command will be enought, no need to edit your php.ini file

```
apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

---

If you are running ubuntu 15.10 or below:

Edit your **php.ini** file, it's located at `/etc/php/[version]/apache2/php.ini` and search for **pdo_mysql**
you might found something like this

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Change it to this

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Save the file and restart apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Check that it's available in your **phpinfo()**

Comment: Just a general FYI, I would **highly** recommend using [MySQLND](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php)(`php-mysqlnd`) instead of the older `php-mysql` package

Comment: Not everyone has the luxury of choosing what library the customer app is already using, and not everyone can just "apt-get"

Comment: Note: "service restart apache2" should read "service apache2 restart".

For Ubuntu 16.04 I used only "sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql" and "sudo service apache2 restart".

Comment: I had to install php-mysql again. Seems some update has been made in that repository.

Comment: Works well with PHP 7.2 as `apt-get install php7.2-mysql`.

Comment: Works well with PHP 8.0 too `apt-get install php8.0-mysql`

Answer (score 42):

First install php-mysql

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
//change the version number based on the php version
```

then enable the module

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
```

and restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Personal +1 for giving the command for enabling the library in php.

Answer (score 6):

On ubuntu 18.04 following works for me

type this in your terminal

For php7.3

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd php7.3-mysql
```

For php7.0

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql
```

For php5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-mysql
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 20 and apache 2.4.x, I didn't need -gd.

`sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql`

Answer (score 5):

First, check if your php.ini has the extension enabled "php_pdo_mysql" and "php_mysqli" and the path of "extension_dir" is correct. If you need one of above configuration, then, you must restart the php-fpm to apply the changes.

In my case (where i am using the Windows OS in the company, i really prefer OSX or Linux), i solved the problem putting this values in the php.ini:

```
; ...

extension_dir = "ext"

; ... 

extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

; ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This only helps if those files are actually present on the system in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on windows, and your php folder is not in your PATH, you have set the absolute directory in your php.ini

for example:

```
extension_dir = "C:/php7/ext"
```

and uncomment

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Restart apache2.4 and it should work.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

1. download the source code of php 7 and extract it.
2. open your terminal
3. swim to the ext/mysqli directory
4. use  commands:

   > phpize
   >
   > ./configure
   >
   > make
   >
   > make install (as root)
5. enable extension=mysqli.so in your php.ini file
6. done!

This worked for me

Comment: Thanks, the same worked for pdo_mysql. Not sure why it isn't compiled as part of default make;make install o_O

Answer (score 2):

I had, pretty much, the same problem. I was able to see that PDO was enabled but I had no available drivers (using PHP 7-RC4). I managed to resolve the issue by adding the php_pdo_mysql extension to those which were enabled.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem on ubunto 20.4 by reinstalling php-mysql.

Remove php-mysql:

```
sudo apt purge php7.2-mysql
```

Then install php-mysql:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-mysql
```

It will add new configurations in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, resolved by actually enabling the extension in the php.ini with the right file name. It was listed as php_pdo_mysql.so but the module name in /lib/php/modules was called just pdo_mysql.so

So just remove the "php_" prefix from the php.ini file and then restart the httpd service and it worked like a charm.

Please note that I'm using Arch and thus path names and services may be different depending on your distrubution.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with the answer then context NOTE this fix was logged above, I'm just re-stating it for anyone googling.

1. Download the source code of php 7 and extract it.
2. open your terminal
3. swim to the ext/pdo_mysql directory
4. use commands:

   phpize

   ./configure

   make

   make install (as root)
5. enable extension=mysqli.so in your php.ini file

This is logged as an answer from here (please upvote it if it helped you too): https://stackoverflow.com/a/39277373/3912517

Context:
I'm trying to add LimeSurvey to the standard WordPress Docker.  The single point holding me back is "PHP PDO driver library" which is "None found"

```
php -i | grep PDO                                                                                  
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_odbc' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_odbc (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_odbc: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_odbc.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_odbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

Ubuntu 16 (Ubuntu 7.3.0)

```
apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

Result:

```
Package 'php7.0-mysql' has no installation candidate
```

Get instructions saying all I have to do is run this:

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

But then I get this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 223: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I try and force some type of UTF:
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/apache2
and I get this:
no valid OpenPGP data found.

Follow some other instructions to run this:
apt-get update
and I get this:
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
and - I think because of that - I then get:

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

By this stage, I'm still getting this on apt-get update:

```
Package 'php7.0-mysql' has no installation candidate.
```

I start trying to add in php libraries, got Unicode issues, tried to get around that and.... you get the idea... whack-a-mole.  I gave up and looked to see if I could compile it and I found the answer I started with.

You might be wondering why I wrote so much? So that anyone googling can find this solution (including me!).

Comment: I have needed to come back here to repeat this, and then had to search down how to find php.ini because my docker install is into a different location: 
php --ini

Answer (score 0):

```
['class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=testdb',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',]
```

It's simple:
Just provide the port number along with the host name
and set default sock path to your `mysql.sock` file path in `php.ini` which the server is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update for those working with installing Linux programs, please note, that things such as 'php7.0-common' are now simply known as 'php-common'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).