# Migration in Laravel 5.6 - could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was searching solution of this problem but i did not find exactly the same which I have. This is all error message:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and
>   table_name = migrations)
>
> at
>   /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
>       660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
>       661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
>       662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
>       663|         catch (Exception $e) {
>
> > 664|             throw new QueryException(
> >         665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> >         666|             );
> >         667|         }
> >         668|
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
>         /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
>
> 2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=forge",
>   "forge", "", [])
>         /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

I tried make command `sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql`and other from this topic [Laravel: Error [PDOException]: Could not Find Driver in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql)
and still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pdo and mysql driver

```
sudo apt-get install php{V}-mysql


sudo apt-get install pdo-mysql
```

replace v with your php version. If your using PostgreSQL, please make sure to change connection in config/database.php or in the .env file

Comment: I did this and I received for php5-mysql

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate

and for pdo-mysql

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pdo-mysql

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-mysql

Comment: The same I got message Reading package lists... Done
  php-mysql
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 207 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,958 B of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php-mysql all 2:7.2+68+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Bad header line Bad header data
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php-defaults/php-mysql_7.2+68+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_all.deb  Bad header line Bad header data

Comment: which version of php are you using?

Comment: PHP 7.1.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728860/php-7-rc3-how-to-install-missing-mysql-pdo

Comment: Finally migration created successfully but I still got message

Comment: Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")
      /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

Comment: in AppServiceProvider boot function add this line Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

Comment: In AppServiceProvider.php line 16:

  Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found

Comment: Ok I added use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; but why I still mesage like in first post...